# Submit um form usando request no php

Tags: php, html, formulário, post, request

Bom dia gente,

Estou fazendo um formulário (trabalho do curso) e preciso dar echo em todas as informações digitadas no formulário usando REQUEST (pode ser POST também) quando eu clicar no botão "submit".

Procurei muito na internet, vi vários vídeos, mas só acho como fazer isso dado a dado, tipo, fazendo uma linha de código para cada dado... mas são muuuuuito dados no formulário e lembro que meu professor fez uma linha só que imprimia todas as informações digitadas, mas não lembro como ele fez isso.

Comment: Dá pra usar `var_dump($_POST)` ou `var_export($_POST)` ou `print_r($_POST)`...

Comment: Eu precisava usar echo e request pq foi o q ele pediu, mas se eu não conseguir vou tentar o que vc falou. É só colocar um dos 03 q vc listou entre a tag de php? preciso referenciar ao arquivo? nunca usei nenhum dos 03.

Comment: `echo var_export($_REQUEST, true);` ou usa um `foreach` e itera sobre todos os campos recebidos

Comment: Obrigada, vou testar assim que chegar em casa.

Answer (score 0):

Além das opções sugeridas pelo Fernando...

Se você precisa **dar echo em todas as informações digitadas no formulário** eu faria assim:

```
echo implode(" ", array_slice($_REQUEST,0,count($_REQUEST) - 1));
```

O `array_slice` vai pegar tudo o que foi digitado menos o submit. Enquanto o `implode` vai juntar todos os valores dos elementos do array colocando um espaçamento entre eles.

Comment: Muito obrigada!!

Comment: @RWProgramer isso funciona caso o submit estiver no final do formulário